# Preparation playbook before other playbook

Tags: ansible

I have 2 playbooks that need to be run one ofter the other.
the first one preapare env (bring other playbook to localhost for example) and the second
use the preperation files and roles.

```
---

- name:  PREP
  import_playbook: prep.yml
  
- name: after
  import_playbook: after.yml
```

I get a compilation error:

RROR! the role 'from_prep_role' was not found in ....
The error appears to be in '/root/dev/ansible-roles/after.yml': line 13, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
  - { role: from_prep_role}
    ^ here
```

How can I solve it?
the first playbook is bringing all the roles that the second use.
thanks

Comment: Without knowing what's inside prep.yml and after.yml, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: prep.yml bring from remote location another role that called: from_prep_role

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "roles" path(s) configuration is missing, at least the path to "from_prep_role" role.
Check your applied "ansible.cfg" file for "**roles_path**" property, should be something like :

```
roles_path = ~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/another/path/to/your/roles:/another/second/path/to/your/other/roles
```

Please note that having many Ansible config. files might lead to unwanted behaviour (Asnible chooses the 1st found and ignore the rest), for details see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file.